# If $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=1 \rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=1 \rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$

How may I prove this? Or give an example where it doesn't apply

Taking into account that $a_n > 0, b_n > 0, \forall n \in N$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to change just, say, $a_1$...

Comment: @Ian When I first say your comment I couldn't understand what you meant with that, but then after reading Pax's answer I do, didn't think about that as a possibility, good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Consider the sequences $a_n = \frac{1}{3^n} $ and $b_n = \frac{1}{3^n - n}$, then 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{3^n} \frac{3^n - n}{1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 - \frac{n}{3^n} \right) = 1,
$$
but their sums are clearly different. Indeed, the first sum is a geometric series, so $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n = \frac{3}{2}$; the second sum can be calculated numerically to be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n \approx 1.70378$.

Answer (score 3):

Take $a_n=\frac{1}{2^n}$ and $b_n=a_n$ for $n>1$ and $b_0=3$. Then $lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1$ clearly and $\sum a_n=\sum b_n+2$.

Comment: Yes! much clearer

Answer (score 1):

this doesn't work in general, your series don't even have to exist, take
$a_n=b_n=2$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ doesn't exists.

Or another example $a_n=b_n=2+(-1)^n$, the same problem with none existing sums...so you need at the very least that the sequences $a_n,b_n$ are converging to $0$ for having the series to be finite.

Okay, I just saw @Ian's comment, you could of course easily change finitely many $a_n$'s and  $b_n$'s. So it actually pretty much never works.

Comment: If neither exists, can they be aid to be "equal"? Need to be careful about definitions here.

Comment: $(-1)^n$ Wouldn't work for this since it needs to be $a_n > 0$

Comment: @Chapi true, but $2+(-1)^n$ does :)

Comment: @Dr.MV why should that exist? only $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=1$ is assumed as far as I can see it, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Apology.  Viewing on my phone.

Comment: @MichaelChirico well, yes and no I would say, but a good point. One thing is clear, that the LHS implies the existence of the series is definitely incorrect, and therefore the implication doesn't hold. It's the usual problem if we are dealing with empty set